# LastInsertId() возвращает 0

Tags: pdo, php

Здравствуйте. В общем, вот такая вот проблема: при попытке получить ID последней внесенной записи PDO всегда возвращает 0.

Сам код запроса:

```
    $prepare = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users`(`pass`, `skype`, `wm`, `group`) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
    $data = array($password, $skype, $wm, $group);

//    print_r($prepare->errorinfo());
    $prepare->execute($data);
    $id = $prepare->lastInsertId();
```

В общем-то, все поля имеют тип TEXT, кроме непоказанного тут поля ID - int, A_I

Вот и вопрос: почему он не возвращает идентефикатор внесенной записи?

Comment: А поле ID - это просто int? Тогда оно не будет работать. Ведь lastInsertId ориентируется не на имя, а на то поле, которое отвечает определенным критериям. Оно должно быть для начала автоинкрементным и не null.

Comment: @KoVadim, поле автоинкрементное, естественно.
____
@KoVadim вот скриншотик, если нужно. http://c2n.me/j65gTQ.png

Comment: На [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313837/getting-last-inserted-row-id-with-pdo-not-suitable-result) описана похожая проблема.

Comment: @KoVadim, посмотрел, ничего толкового, кроме выдержки из документации, не обнаружил.

Comment: Там предлагают сделать прямой вызов в виде `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` (да, это такой sql запрос, который возвращает одну запись с одного поля) и посмотреть на результат.

Answer (score 2):

А у вас код точно работает? Просто `lastInsertId()` вызывается у объекта-подключения(`PDO`), а не у подготовленного запроса(`PDOStatement`).

**Обновление**

`$db->prepare()` - возвращает объект класса [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.pdostatement.php), у которого **НЕТ** метода `lastInsertId()`

---

Предоставленный вами код должен выдать `Fatal error`.

Comment: @mantigatos, запись в базу проходит, но lastinsertid() ничего не отдаёт